# Embedding an excel document into an application with excel online

Tags: excel, onedrive, office365api, office-js

I have been experimenting with excel online shared link to be able to embed an excel document to our internal web site. But this method is not viable because we can't actually make a public link because the data is private.

I was wondering if it was possible to embed an excel document any other way. I can add that we need an excel document with an add-in attached to it. I might have done something wrong but in my test, my add-in didn't show up in the embedded version of the document. I also noted that functionality seemed greatly reduced. Even with read-write permissions, I could input some data but couldn't delete anything which wasn't very useful in our case.
Ref:https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Share-it-Embed-an-Excel-workbook-on-your-web-page-or-blog-from-OneDrive-804e1845-5662-487e-9b38-f96307144081

Our goal is to be able to :

1. embed excel document into an application.
2. feed external data into the excel document when opened or on user input (done by an add-in)
3. user interaction (read-write-delete according to defined locks and column visibility)
4. save the relevant data to storage (done by an add-in)
5. save the document to OneDrive and/or to a specific location.

I am wondering if there is any solutions (now or in-progress) that would allow us to have most of the functionality of excel online while being managed by an application.

Possible solutions?:

We might have a partial solution where instead of creating a shared link, we could integrate our application to excel instead of doing thing the other way around. But it doesn't solve how to handle Microsoft accounts required to access the documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to do the heavy lifting in JavaScript I'm afraid and add-ins are out of the question. See a very rudimentary example of how to interact with an embedded Excel file here:
http://www.jkp-ads.com/Articles/embeddedexcel00.asp

Comment: I can see what can be done with Excel Web App, It seem to work for viewing and partialy editing a workbook, but we need more than that.  I might be wrong but it seem to be that we will have the same limitation than embeded shared links from OneDrive.